# how to get latest date records of each user in yii

Tags: mysql, yii

Im working workers report display for the last date.

I want to get records of last date reports of single user and need to display total time they spend to complete single project for last date in yii.

My table structure is:

```
id  worker  project  total_time   date
---------------------------------------------
 1   6        2      1370932128   20-12-2017
 2   9        3      1370931664   20-12-2017
 3   12       5      1370933037   20-12-2017
 4   12       6      1370932128   19-12-2017
```

Currently my work_report table model query is

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'a';
$criteria->select = 'a.*, worker.*, project.*, SUM(a.total_time) as groupbysum, max(a.date) as MaxDate';
$criteria->with = array('worker','project');

$criteria->condition = 'a.date=worker.MaxDate';


$criteria->group = 'a.project, a.worker';
$criteria->order = 'worker.worker_name ASC';


$new_criteria = clone $criteria;
$new_criteria->select = "SUM(a.total_time) as sum";
$new_criteria->group = '';
$new_result = WorkReport::model()->find($new_criteria);
```

Its not working. it showing me sql error and i dont have an idea to fix this issue.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'worker.MaxDate' in 'where clause'.

Comment: Please post your full table structure and expected output of query/result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias and aggregation result  in  where condition   but you can use having  for filter result based on aggregated  result ..  eg:

```
$criteria->having= 'a.date=worker.MaxDate';
```